# How Can I Sum Django Models Field by Dates and Display Totals base on Current Month and Year

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I am a novice in python Django framework and I wish someone should please help on some piece of code I have been struggling with hours.
I have an Expenditure Model with date and amount Fields among others, and I want to calculate total amount for the current month and display in django template through the views using the context dictionary.
Here is my Expenditure model code:

```
class Expenditure(models.Model):
      amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
      date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=False)
```

Views.py codes here:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
from django.db import connection

def index(request):
    truncate_month = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month','day')
    total_income = Income.objects.extra({'month': truncate_month}).values('date').annotate(Sum('amount'))
    context = {
         'total_income':total_income,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

This is how I am trying to display the Sum Total of amount for the current month and year in Django template.

```
{% for income in total_income %}
   {{income.date}}{{income.amount}}
{% endfor %}
```

The result of my code above is displaying the months of dates from the Expenditure Model on the template **whereas this is the only Output Result I am expecting: 'Aug. 2021: 13,000' Only Because August is the only current Month in 2021.** Your kind assistance would help a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you just didn't use the truncated fields in your `values` call.

In line with that, you can use django's [`TruncMonth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) to annotate and group by the month:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth


total_income = Income.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))

context = {
     'total_income': total_income,
}
```

And then in your template, use those annotated fields like this:

```
{% for income in total_income %}
  {{ income.month }} {{ income.total_amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**:

If you just need it on the current month and year, just filter on that and run an aggregate like:

```
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now()
total_income = Income.objects.filter(
    date__year=now.year, date__month=now.month
).aggregate(total_income=Sum('total_income'))['total_income']

context = {
    'year': now.year,
    'month': now.strftime('%B'),
    'total_income': total_income,
}
```

In the template, no need to iterate on anything:

```
  {{ year }} - {{ month }} : {{ total_income }}
```

Comment: Thanks @bdbd for your answer. It has given me solution 90% because the output is showing sum totals of all the months in the database whereas I wish to get only for the current month which is August, 2021. You further input will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am Very Sorry, bdbd, Your edited answer solved the problem initially but  I was the one that wrongly pasted your code into mine. Actually this is the output your answer: 2021 - 8 : 13000. And would be much grateful to get the Month written in words like August. Thanks so much.